# Game center achievements vs game state (achievements)

Tags: ios, game-center

I posted a similar thread on Unity answers (that's the engine that I'm using) but no answers there, so I might as well try here.  This question is not specific to Unity anyway, but to iOS.

The question here is trying to sync the game center and game state (since a game could store information outside of game center) in a way that would not annoy users.

Imagine this scenario: the player gets an achievement for beating the first five levels of a game, and each level counts for 20% of that achievement. Naturally, game center notifies the user of the achievement percentage after each successive level (20% after level 1, 40% after level 2, and so on).

What if the user deletes the game, then decides to reinstall it? This means that the game state stored on the phone is lost, and they must start from scratch. Should the game:

**a) Reset all game center achievements to be in sync with app state, thus reset the five-level achievement to 0%**

--or--

**b) Update game center achievement ONLY if the player makes more progress relative to it.**

Option b) seems superior, since I don't think that my game center achievement list reseted when I deleted and reinstalled a few of my games. If the player is hell-bent on resetting achievements, that is possible but should be independent of option b) here.

Since I am talking about achievements that increment percentages, like the one shown here: do you think it's wise to take an old game center percentage number and add to it each time you want to update it (i.e. add to it)? Or just re-calculate the percentage each time? The latter solution seems better since I'm OCD in regards to accuracy issues relating to floating point numbers (especially if an achievement is increment thousands of times?)...but game center DOES use doubles, not single-precision floats. Thanks...